# Login webpages not loading correctly

Tags: internet

Sorry for the vague description as i do not know how to properly describe this problem.

When some web pages are loaded, the formatting will be the wrong size and in strange places. in addition every drop down menu appears without prompting and it seems to not be able to load certain data.

This only seems to occur on web pages that require a login, and only after they have been logged into or I am on the login page. (parent pay, squadlist,

It occurs on chrome, internet explorer and Microsoft edge on two windows 10 PCs.
It also appears to occur on an apple tablet using its browser safari.(parent pay shown here) [image: Parent pay]

What is happening and how worried should i be?

Comment: We can not awnser this without more details, (like are there requests that fail, what is in the browser logs..
Also, in its current form its not a Security question, but a generic StackExchange question (its about Browsers not the security of a website / browser)

Comment: Worried in terms of security, probably not much at this stage (based on the information provided). It looks like some of the files aren't loaded (CSS and/or Javascript files, mostly). It's possible something else that is loaded before those files is blocked, which in turns blocks loading those files (depending on the way they are all linked together). In Chrome, type Ctrl-Shift-I (or Command-Option-I on a Mac) to open the developer tools. Go to the "Network" tab and check for any resources that don't load (or take a very long time to load), that may provide some hints as to the source.

Comment: Went onto devtools and found GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: as this is not a security problem should i take down?

Comment: This is not a security problem. The site is having an issue on their end.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens on multiple devices on the same connection then its possible that there is some filtering at the router, at the ISP, or you are using the same AV solution that is also blocking some content. If you are using ad-blockers, or anti-tracking plug-ins on all devices, turn them off and re-try.

If it happens on multiple devices on different connections (office, home, 4G) then it's a little more complex to debug?